# Huge space before xtabular

Tags: tables, multicol, xtab

**Description**

I have a tex file similar to the following, where I use xtabular in multicols enviroment. However, I find that xtabular starts a new column when there is enough space for an entry. Also, there is an empty table at the end.

**Tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array, xtab}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\let\mcnewpage=\newpage
\newcommand{\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols}{%
  \renewcommand\newpage{%
    \if@firstcolumn
      \hrule width\linewidth height0pt
      \columnbreak
    \else
      \mcnewpage
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext

\begin{center}
\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols
\tablehead{
\hline 
blindtext \tabularnewline
}
\tabletail{\hline}
\begin{xtabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{.9\columnwidth}|}
\hline 
\blindtext \tabularnewline
\hline 
\blindtext \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{xtabular}
\end{center}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: like almost all table environments xtab can not break within a cell. A page/column break can only occur only between rows. If there is really only one column, then of course you don't need a table at all (and most two column tables are better set at as a list, which would also allow breaking)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is just an example. My real table, of course, contains more than 2 columns. Otherwise, I don't have to bother about it.

Comment: You'd think that would be the case but you don't want to know how many "real" one column tables I've been sent over the years, so I thought it worth saying:-) So in that case basically there is nothing you can do breaking a table mid row is hard and not possible in general as you have to find compatible break points in each column.